# trying to unpack firmware update with non standard compression

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, compression, unpack, squashfs

I am trying to unpack a clear spot firmware update

The firmware I am trying to reverse can be found on the [download page of the vendor](http://www.clear.com/support/download/spots/clear-spot-voyager) I have used the fwtools to unpack the firmware as described on [this page](http://hackspot.net/iSpotBlog/?p=177).

After I did this, I managed to get a "kernel.bin" and a "rootfs.bin". Now I want to include a new/additional certificate to this modem and make some edits on the administrator page that is within this modem (a Wimax one).

So I checked the rootfs file using the `file` tool. And I got the following output:

```
rootfs.bin: Linux Compressed ROM File System data, little endian size 4280320 version #2 sorted_dirs CRC 0xbf224100, edition 16777728, 268441607 blocks, 1325400384 files
```

This was no to little help so I gave `binwalk` a try and I got this:

```
    DECIMAL     HEX         DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
14944       0x3A60      LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: -1 bytes 
855040      0xD0C00     Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.1, size: 4276396 bytes, 1028 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Fri Jun 22 23:02:36 2012
```

As this did stoke me as odd I didn't continue. I don't know how to unpack the firmware. I think I have tried about everything I know you can do manually, firmware mod fit, fwtools, the whole lot!

Can someone shed some light on my issue and tell me how to continue?

and another question , if i replaced the "rootfs.bin" with another one extracted from  firmware update for another device and another company , it will work if i recompress the "kernel.bin" and the new "rootfs.bin" and update the clear device with the new update ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use some clues from [here](https://github.com/elvanderb/TCP-32764/blob/master/backdoor_description_for_those_who_don-t_like_pptx.pdf?raw=true). Same problem described on pages 13-14.